# Python print() Terminal dump after cronjob has finished

Tags: python, linux, cron, command-line-interface

Just wondering - as a fail safe backup, I'm setting up a python cronjob script that I can print various things to the terminal.

I was wondering, once the cronjob has finished - am I able to take a terminal dump for the last output? Even if it errors out...

Probably going to be running on a Linux VPS - CentOS (not sure if that 100% matters).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect all prints /dev/tty to print in all terminals `python exec.py &> /dev/tty)`. But cron is execute deattached from all terminals.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [shell redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

Your code would be something like

`33 3 * * * /path/to/some_job.sh 5> /var/log/cron.log`